# How do I connect to a SQL instance running on Google Cloud from NodeJS?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, google-cloud-platform

I have currently deployed a NodeJS application on a Kubernetes engine, and I want to send SQL queries to the SQL instance on Google Cloud. What's the best approach to doing this?

Comment: why have you tagged sql-server then?

Comment: Did you look for your different options? There are different solutions according to your db engine and your configuration. Is it SQL server ou Cloud SQL? another db engine? Is it hosted on a VM? in the K8S cluster? Do you have a public IP or a private IP on the database? If a private IP, is it in the same VPC as your cluster???

Answer (score 0):

Following the official [Cloud SQL Connecting from Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine) . The recommended procedure to connect to the SQL instance is by using the [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy),it will be added to your pod using the sidecar container pattern. This setup has multiple advantages in terms of security and resilience.

But take into account that it's possible to connect to the SQL Instance [without Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#private-ip) by using private IP, but only when it belongs to the same VPC network.